# How to run a cmd command on wake (windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-line

I want to open my cmd and run a cmd command every time my computer wakes up. The command i want to run is:

```
cd desktop -> cd instabotfinal -> python main.py
```

I have a windows machine. so just wondering what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a shortcut, which defines both the target command `"P:\ath\to\python.exe"` and the argument `"main.py"`, then use the start in location as `"%UserProfile%\Desktop\instabotfinal"`, and place that shortcut into your startup directory? You could even specifically run `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` as your target executable and use `/D /K ""P:\ath\to\python.exe" "main.py""` as the arguments to it, depending upon your needs.

Comment: If you want something to restart upon wake, as opposed to startup, then you may find that a Scheduled Task is more suitable than a shortcut, as already mentioned _(the options for configuring it should be similar to the shortcut method, just us a more appropriate location, if needed)_.

Comment: the problem is i need to run it each time the laptop opens from sleep. i know calling a cmd prompt isn't usually done but its just a temp measure to help debug some things. im having problems with dependencies that require virtual environment that's why i need to run it from the cmd line upon awaking. any ideas?

Comment: thanks i got it working by using the task scheduler on the pc. it worked a charm